# How do I change the references folder of a lot of Visual Studio projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Here's an awkward one: We're cleaning up some old C# code. It had a great number of hard dependencies. We've replaced all the hard dependencies with NuGet dependencies.

However, now when we build the project it's placing all of it's downloaded dependencies in `C:\Assemblies`. Because (iirc?) Visual Studio only uses relative paths, I suspect it's actually going to `"..\..\..\Assemblies"` or some such, and so depends on the directory it's placed in. It also seems to be creating some other Assemblies folders in other parent directories, so it's not even consistent.

This problem affects dozens of solutions each with a dozen or more projects. I'd like to replace them all with something consistent that isn't going to cause problems. Going one level up (ie `"..\Assemblies\"`) might work, but different solutions are different numbers of folders deep. Perhaps it'd be better just to give each project their own `/lib/` folder (which I think is standard practice?).

What do I need to change- is it only the `OutputPath` and the `HintPath` parameters in the csproj files, or is there more? Is there some nice automated way to do this or am I going to have to manually change every csproj file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, now when we build the project it's placing all of it's downloaded dependencies in C:\Assemblies... It also seems to be creating some other Assemblies folders in other parent directories, so it's not even consistent.

That because there should have several configuration files `NuGet.Config` exists on your machine. You can refer to the official document: [Configuring NuGet behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) for more detail info.

The default references folder is in the solution directory, we could use `repositoryPath` in the `nuget.config` to change the default value.

```
<configuration>
    <config>
      <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\Packages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Besides, any number of NuGet.Config files can exist on a machine, both in global locations and within a project's folder structure. This allows you to control settings in different places as they apply to a project, a group of projects, or all projects.

So there should be multiple nuget.config files on your machine, which resulting in inconsistent reference folders for your different solutions.

To resolve this issue, you need clean the other `nuget.config` files on your machine except the global `nuget.config`, which located at the path `%appdata%\NuGet`, and configure the `repositoryPath` to the folder where you want save your references. It can be a relative path or an absolute path.

If you want set the references folder to the special directory for some solution, you can add a NuGet.config file next to your solution file .sln, and configure the `repositoryPath`. This file will only change the references folder for current solution.

> What do I need to change- is it only the OutputPath and the HintPath parameters in the csproj files, or is there more? Is there some nice automated way to do this or am I going to have to manually change every csproj file?

You do not need to change .csproj file manually, after you configured the `repositoryPath`, colse you Visual studio, then re-open it, There will be a prompt to tell you restore the packages when you open the Package Manager Console or Manage NuGet package for solution. Waiting for the restore to complete. Then you just use the command line:

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

in the Package Manager Console window, NuGet will update `HintPath` parameters in the csproj files automatically.

See [How to reinstall and update packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) for more detail info.

Comment: Thank you mate, this was really informative and useful.